# get error order vcf via api: requires a preset configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I try to verify an order of vcf. and i got the following errors. what preset configuration i should use?  also my payload is attached. do you have an example to order an vcf?

```
 {
   "error": "Invalid data on the order for property: packageId. Package (737) requires a preset configuration.",
  "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidData"
}
```

the order payload

{
          "location": 957095,
          "quantity": 1,
          "packageId": 737,
          "hardware": [
            {
              "hostname": "rcvtest1",
              "domain": "softlayer.com"
            }
          ],
          "prices": [
            {
              "id": 176999
            },
            {
              "id": 165709
            },
            {
              "id": 44988
            },
            {
              "id": 1915
            },
            {
              "id": 49809
            },
            {
              "id": 49809
            },
            {
              "id": 50141
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 50141
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 49819
            },
            {
              "id": 50231
            },
            {
              "id": 2397
            },
            {
              "id": 21
            },
            {
              "id": 58
            },
            {
              "id": 420
            },
            {
              "id": 57
            },
            {
              "id": 55
            },
            {
              "id": 418
            },
            {
              "id": 906
            }
          ]
        }
      }

Comment: how did you get that package? the SoftLayer_Account::getActivePackages should list that package however it is missing, also in order to list the avaialabe presets for the package you should use this method SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets but the result is empty what led me to think that this package is not functional yet.

Comment: i got it from SoftLayer_Product_Package/AllObjects. this pkg may not be ready yet.

Comment: yep it is not ready

Comment: but i can order vcf from bluemix UI. link below. do you mean i am not able to order the same via api? https://console.ng.bluemix.net/infrastructure/vmware-solutions/console?ace_config=%7B%22redirect%22:%22https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/%22,%22bluemixUIVersion%22:%22v5%22%7D#CreateSDDC

Comment: I cannot see that page I have not an account for that, but you only can order the same servers that are being listed in the softlayer control portal https://control.softlayer.com other kind of servers cannot be ordered via API.